# Remote Named Pipes connection refused on XP

Tags: windows-xp, named-pipes

I've got a simple design I'm trying to implement.

A single C++ based server app creates a write-only named pipe. Multiple clients (C++ or C#) connect as read-only and listen for status messages.

I have this working for local processes, but I am unable to connect a client on a different host to the server.

The server is running on XP SP2 (maybe SP3). The client is running on Win7.

```
    SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR sd;
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa;
    SID_IDENTIFIER_AUTHORITY siaWorldSidAuthority = SECURITY_WORLD_SID_AUTHORITY;
    PSID psidWorldSid = (PSID) LocalAlloc  (LPTR, GetSidLengthRequired(1));
    InitializeSid(psidWorldSid, &siaWorldSidAuthority, 1);
    *(GetSidSubAuthority(psidWorldSid, 0)) = SECURITY_WORLD_RID;
    InitializeSecurityDescriptor(&sd, SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_REVISION);
    SetSecurityDescriptorGroup(&sd, psidWorldSid, TRUE);
    ZeroMemory(&sa, sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES));
    sa.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
    sa.lpSecurityDescriptor = &sd;
    sa.bInheritHandle = FALSE;

    HANDLE hPipe = CreateNamedPipe(
        lpszPipename,               // name
        PIPE_ACCESS_OUTBOUND,       // write access 
        PIPE_TYPE_MESSAGE |             // message type pipe 
        PIPE_READMODE_MESSAGE |         // message-read mode 
        PIPE_WAIT,                      // blocking mode 
        PIPE_UNLIMITED_INSTANCES,   // max. instances 
        BUFSIZE,                    // output buffer size 
        BUFSIZE,                    // input buffer size 
        PIPE_TIMEOUT,               // client time-out 
        NULL /*&sa*/);                      // no security attribute
```

replacing the NULL with &sa in the final param has no effect. The C# client code looks like this.

```
        SafeFileHandle pipeHandle = 
           CreateFile(
              pipeName,
              GENERIC_READ,
              0,
              IntPtr.Zero,
              OPEN_EXISTING,
              0,
              IntPtr.Zero);
```

What stupidly obvious thing am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your firewall? Is port 445 blocked?

Comment: XP is running in a VM on the Win7 host. I believe that Windows Firewall is disabled both on the host and the VM. I believe the VM networking adapter isn't doing any filtering.

Of course, the word "believe" is an important caveat here.

Comment: On the other hand, I was having trouble earlier when both the client and server were on the same machine, but instead of having a pipe named "\\.\pipe\foo" I was using "\\12.34.56.78\pipe\foo" (well, with the actual IP address, of course) -- this seemed to have connection failures even when both processes were local.

Comment: Josh, I found this KB article on using named pipes on XP. There's some setup involved... http://support.microsoft.com/kb/925890